# How to bury *Ibuffer* when switching to another buffer?

Tags: buffers, ibuffer

1. `M-x ibuffer`
2. Select a buffer
3. Kill that buffer

The `*Ibuffer*` buffer re-appears. How can I get it to behave more like a `*Help*` buffer, which is buried (dropped to the end of the "recently used" list) when you switch away from it (so it doesn't appear undesirably like this)?

I formerly used `electric-buffer-list`, which had the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we type `C-h m` in an `*Ibuffer*` buffer, we see that there is more than one way to select/open a buffer.  When I place my cursor on a file in an `*Ibuffer*` buffer and type `C-h k` and then press the enter key, I get a `*Help*` buffer that describes the function `ibuffer-visit-buffer`.  If I were type type `M-x find-function RET ibuffer-visit-buffer RET`, then I could examine the function at issue, which looks like this:

```lisp
(defun ibuffer-visit-buffer (&optional single)
  "Visit the buffer on this line.
If optional argument SINGLE is non-nil, then also ensure there is only
one window."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((buf (ibuffer-current-buffer t)))
    (switch-to-buffer buf)
    (when single
      (delete-other-windows))))
```

I am guessing that the original poster is most interested in changing the behavior of `ibuffer-visit-buffer` so that the `*Ibuffer*` gets "*burried*".  As such, we could just add the following statement `(bury-buffer (current-buffer))` and redefine the function at issue, place it in our `.emacs` / `init.el` file, and restart Emacs:

```lisp
(require 'ibuffer)

(defun ibuffer-visit-buffer (&optional single)
  "Visit the buffer on this line.
If optional argument SINGLE is non-nil, then also ensure there is only
one window."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((buf (ibuffer-current-buffer t)))
    (bury-buffer (current-buffer))
    (switch-to-buffer buf)
    (when single
      (delete-other-windows))))
```

Note that we could just have easily killed the `*Ibuffer*` buffer by using `(kill-buffer (current-buffer))`, since generating a new `*Ibuffer*` buffer is virtually instantaneous .....

Comment: Thanks very much for your "teach them to fish" details. For some reason `bury-buffer` didn't work, but `kill-buffer` did.

Answer (score 0):

Since emacs-27 there is a simple way to do this using `switch-to-prev-buffer-skip`:

```
(defun my-switch-to-prev-buffer-skip-p (win buf bury-or-kill)
  (string= (buffer-name buf) "*Ibuffer*"))

(setq switch-to-prev-buffer-skip #'my-switch-to-prev-buffer-skip-p)
```

The function should return t for buffers that you want to skip.